# Center figure in section

Tags: html, css, figure

I cant get these figures to centered. They're inside a section, I've tried so many variations. All is as it should be, they float in the right way. But no matter what I try with the sections or figure codes, they still do not center within the sections.

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: none;
  background-color: #373B44;
  height: 100vh;
}

section:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: white;
}

figure.snip1165 {
  float: left;
  margin: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<section>

  <figure class="snip1165">
    <img src="http://test.nationalparkpaws.com/images/camping%20in%20mountains%20with%20ten.jpg" />
    <figcaption>
      <h3>Useful Tips</h3>
      <p>
        Sometimes I think the surest sign that intelligent life exists elsewhere in the universe is that none of it has tried to contact us.
      </p>

    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="snip1165 red">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample63.jpg" alt="sample63" />
    <figcaption>
      <h3>Caspian<span> Bellevedere</span></h3>
      <p>
        I don't need to compromise on my principles, because they don't have the slightest bearing on what happens to me anyway.
      </p>

    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="snip1165 orange">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample64.jpg" alt="sample64" />
    <figcaption>
      <h3>Parsley<span> Montana</span></h3>
      <p>
        That's the problem with nature, something's always stinging you or oozing mucous all over you. Hobbes, I think it is time you and me when and watched some TV.
      </p>

    </figcaption>
  </figure>

</section>
```

Comment: Vertically or Horizontal or both side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-align: center;` on the `section` and remove `float: left;` on `figure` and use `display: inline-block; and vertical-align: top;` instead.

Should do the trick, see below snippet :

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: none;
  background-color: #373B44;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

section:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: white;
}

figure.snip1165 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<section>  
  <figure class="snip1165">
    <img src="http://test.nationalparkpaws.com/images/camping%20in%20mountains%20with%20ten.jpg"/>
    <figcaption>
      <h3>Useful Tips</h3>
      <p>
        Sometimes I think the surest sign that intelligent life exists elsewhere in the universe is that none of it has tried to contact us.
      </p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="snip1165 red">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample63.jpg" alt="sample63"/>
    <figcaption>
      <h3>Caspian<span> Bellevedere</span></h3>
      <p>
        I don't need to compromise on my principles, because they don't have the slightest bearing on what happens to me anyway.
      </p>    
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure class="snip1165 orange">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample64.jpg" alt="sample64"/>
    <figcaption>
      <h3>Parsley<span> Montana</span></h3>
      <p>
        That's the problem with nature, something's always stinging you or oozing mucous all over you. Hobbes, I think it is time you and me when and watched some TV.
      </p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>  
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very much appreciated :-)